# ¿Cuál es el nombre o la clase de los temas/plantillas que traen un espacio para insertar reproducir video, al principio de la página?

Tags: wordpress-theme

Hay plantillas como la de esta página que reproducen un video al principio o cabecera de la pagina, ¿como se llaman estos temas o su clasificación?
Parecido a esta página:
http://incmty.com/

Answer (score 0):

Este es un Ejemplo de mi Pagina, este es el enlace [Ver](http://uati.com.mx/)

Utilize el Siguiente Codigo

```
<div id="video-section" class="video-section">
    <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'mELQ39fcFls',containment:'.video-section', showControls:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, vol:50, mute:true, startAt:10, opacity:1, addRaster:true, quality:'default', optimizeDisplay:true}">My video</a> <!--BsekcY04xvQ-->
</div>
```

Otra Opcion es utilizar la etiqueta div de video. Ejemplo

```
<video src="ruta" controls>
<object data="archivo.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param value="archivo.swf" name="movie"/>
</object>
 </video>
```

Comment: la maquetaste tu verdad sin plantilla wordpress?

Comment: Si, no es codigo Wordpress.

Comment: de acuerdo, intentaré gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas son temas con video de fondo, en ingles video background, podrías buscar algún plugin en wordpress.org para hacer esto, por ejemplo:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/video-background/

O también puedes buscar algún tema que ya lo implemente como los siguientes:

https://themeforest.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=video+background&as=1&type=c&category=wordpress&referrer=homepage

Comment: ¿cualquiera de ellos se puede importar a wordpress sin problema? alguno, claro después de pagarlo